# how to create subfloat figures (two in first row and one below)

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I am importing chapters and caption2.sty  How to create subfloat figures or subfigures(two in first row and one below)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the `subcaption` package, and by the way, replace `subcaption2` with the newer `caption` package (which has the same author as `subcaption`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \subcaptionbox{a subfigure in a \cs{subcaptionbox}}
      {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}
  \quad
    \subcaptionbox{another subfigure, also in a \cs{subcaptionbox}}
      {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]\ContinuedFloat
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A figure with subfigures}
  \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]